# Autonumber field postmigration issue

Tags: managed-package, package

As we know that Autonumber field in standard object cannot be packaged. So Before creating package I converted the Autonumber to Text field and after installation in a scracth org I tried to change the Field type of that field but I am not able to do that. Even I cant delete that field.I am getting this Error
`This Custom Field Definition is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes.`
Is there a way we can achieve this as post installation step?.